# Why can't I append this data to my numpy array? Getting a dimensional error

Tags: python, numpy, append

I'm trying to make my program faster. I'm utilizing numpy arrays to store randomly generated data. While profiling, I've found that the append function is significantly slowing down the program. I'm trying to pre-allocate full size of the array, and append at the given indice of the for loop. I'm getting dimensional errors.

I've tried changing the code to:

```
    myarray.empty([0, numberOfRows])
    myarray.empty([numberOfRows, 0])
    myarray.empty(numberOfRows)
```

That's about it. I don't know what else to try. When I did:

```
     myarray.empty([numberOfRows, numberOfRows])
```

I got an error saying the array was too large.

```
    sysIdList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
    systemIdArray = np.empty([0, numberOfRows])
    numberOfRows = random.randint(10000, 20000)
    for x in range(numberOfRows):
        systemId = random.choice(sysIdList)
        systemIdArray = np.append(systemIdArray[x], str(systemId))


        systemIdArray = np.append(systemIdArray[x], str(systemId))
    IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: Why aren't you using list append?

Comment: From everything I've read and when I originally wrote the program, numpy arrays were significantly faster. But getting this error it might be worth it to just switch all the numpy arrays to lists and use that. Welcome any feedback.

Comment: One thing is not clear: do you want to create an array and replace row `i` with another row, or do you want to just append things to an empty list? In the first case `numpy` is better as you are essentially operating with a matrix, in the second case I would use lists and not pre-allocate anything

Comment: Numpy arrays are faster if you vectorize the problem, which means if you operate on the full array all at once, instead of doing it element by element. If you use append, just use a list

Comment: Ok I'll try and switch everything to lists. this is just one example of 20+ lists in the same program so it may speed up substantially.

Comment: Not everything in `numpy` is faster.  `np.append` makes a new array each time, with lots of copying.  `alist.append` just adds a pointer to the list. And as you found out, getting the dimensions right is tricky with `np.append` (or `np.concatenate`).

Comment: Why not change systemIdArray = np.append(systemIdArray[x], str(systemId))  to systemIdArray[x] = str(systemId)?  Did I miss somethng in the question?

Comment: For an array with shape (0,n], index with [0] produces this error.